# Kinesis guaranteed ordering with Bulk PutRecords

Tags: amazon-kinesis

i read that kinesis has shard level ordering. I wanted to ask how does this work with PutRecords if i am putting 500 records and 100 fail from the middle... that in my logic would mean that the writes would go out of order because the retried records go now im the back... or is there some mechanism that makes it work ?  Also i am not interested in global ordering only orderig per partition key